# how get data json with parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

i have url : http://cgncrdev.gandsoft.com/ws/get.php?fcid=gen_ncr_id&origin_id=OR10&suborigin_id=OR13

anyway, you can open it url..

i try this but not working

```
function gen_ncr_id() {
    $.getJSON(baseUrl + '/ws/get.php?fcid=gen_ncr_id&origin_id=OR10&suborigin_id=OR13', function(data) {
        $.each(data.items, function(key, val) {
            alert(val.gen_ncr_id)
            opt = '<input type="text" value="' + val.gen_ncr_id + '">'
            $(opt).appendTo('#id_ncr')
        })
    })
}
```

output : undefined

can help me ?

Comment: are you actually receiving the array in `data` ?

Comment: `console.log(val["gen_ncr_id('OR10','OR13')"]);`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
var data = {"items":[{"gen_ncr_id('OR10','OR13')":"4.13\/4.10.4\/16\/002"}]};
function getPrefixValue(obj, prefix) {
  var result;
  var re = new RegExp('^' + prefix);
  $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
    if (key.match(re)) {
      result = value;
      return false; // break the each loop
    }
  });
  return result;
}
$.each(data.items, function(key, val) {
  var value = getPrefixValue(val, 'gen_ncr_id');
  alert(value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```